# How private function created with closure can access variable defined in constructor?

Tags: javascript, closures

I have the following code :

```
var TagCloud = (function() {
  var createTagsArray = function() {
    j$("#" + this.cloudId + " a").each(function(index) {
      //bla bla
    });
  }

  function TagCloud(cloudId) {
    this.cloudId = cloudId;
  };

  TagCloud.prototype.createTagCloud = function(){
    createTagsArray(this.cloudId);            
  };

  return TagCloud;
}());

new TagCloud("tagcloud");
```

I create TagCloud object. I create it with closure to have a private function *createTagArray*. However inside this function I would have an access to variable defined in TagCloud constructor - *cloudId*. Of course in this example I cannot get it using *this*. But is there anyway to get it ? (I wouldn't like to pass this value as function *createTagArray* parameter).

It can be also my mistake in understanding usage of closure, because I've started working with closures.

Comment: How would you typically call `createTagsArray`? Would this be called by the `TagCloud` constructor?

Comment: Look at my edit. I would like to use it from public function createTagCloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the variable through closure, for that you would need to define the `createTagsArray` function within the `TagCloud` constructor function - and then you couldn't access it from the `createTagCloud` method any more without making it public.

But I don't think you want access to the variable anyway. You want access to the `.cloudId` property of your instance, and for that you need the instance.

Passing it - either the property value or the complete instance - as a parameter would be preferred actually. There's nothing wrong with that:

```
var createTagsArray = function(cloudId) {
  j$("#" + cloudId + " a").each(function(index) {
    //bla bla
  });
}
TagCloud.prototype.createTagCloud = function(){
  createTagsArray(this.cloudId);
};
```

And using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) you could even pass the instance itself so that you can access it as `this`:

```
var createTagsArray = function() {
  j$("#" + this.cloudId + " a").each(function(index) {
    //bla bla
  });
}
TagCloud.prototype.createTagCloud = function(){
  createTagsArray.call(this);
};
```

From there you could even easily switch (back and forth) to a semi-private method:

```
TagCloud.prototype._createTagsArray = function() {
  j$("#" + this.cloudId + " a").each(function(index) {
    //bla bla
  });
}
TagCloud.prototype.createTagCloud = function(){
  this._createTagsArray();
};
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I wanted to confirm that, It's possible or not. And using "call" - this is also what I was looking for, because I tried to pass and instance of TagCloud object without succes. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```js
function TagCloud(cloudId) {
  var self = this;
  self.createTagsArray = function() {
    console.log(this);
  }

  self.cloudId = cloudId;
  self.createTagCloud = function() {
    self.createTagsArray()
  }
  
  return{
    "cloudId": cloudId,
    "createTagCloud": self.createTagCloud
  }
};

var obj = new TagCloud("tagcloud");
obj.createTagCloud();

var obj = new TagCloud("TagCloudTest");
obj.createTagCloud();
```

Comment: with your solution function createTagsArray become again public. I would like to hide it and this is way I use closure for it. Look at my edit. I would like to use createTagsArray function in other public function

Comment: thank you, your solution is right. However do you know if it's possible to get this variable in closure scope ? I'm confused about this and it made me really curious